# SQLException: database is locked despite closing all resources

Tags: java, multithreading, sqlite

I'm trying to debug a multi-threaded application which processes one file as input and writes to an SQLite database.

Within the application I create 4 threads, with each thread writing to a separate .db file to prevent any synchronization/file access issues. I'm getting a database is locked error despite the fact that I'm using try with resources in addition to explicitly closing any resources I open after I'm done with them. Here's my code (inside of the thread object):

```
public void run() {
    String path = database + num + ".db";
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path);
         PreparedStatement insertReview = conn.prepareStatement("insert into reviews (" +
                 "reviewerID, " +
                 "asin, " +
                 "rating, " +
                 "title, " +
                 "content, " +
                 "helpfulVotes, " +
                 "totalVotes) values (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7);");) {
        System.out.println("Writing from thread " + num);
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        int x = 1;
        for (Object[] review : reviews) {
            insertReview.setString(1, (String) review[0]);
            insertReview.setString(2, (String) review[1]);
            insertReview.setDouble(3, (Double) review[2]);
            insertReview.setString(4, (String) review[3]);
            insertReview.setString(5, (String) review[4]);
            insertReview.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt((String) review[5]));
            insertReview.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt((String) review[6]));
            insertReview.addBatch();
            //System.out.println("Processed review " + x + " of " + reviews.size() + " in " + num);
            x++;
        }

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Executing batch in " + num);
        insertReview.executeBatch();
        insertReview.close();
        conn.commit();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Thread" + num);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I open the connection and the prepared statement with a "try with resource," and then close them both at the end of the try block. What happens is that the program will run fine for a while (with threads being created, run, and dying) and then I'll seemingly randomly get this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
```

which either points me to the line where I call

```
insertReview.executeBatch();
```

or

```
conn.commit();
```

or the line inside the try declaration where I create the prepared statement, and the thread the exception is thrown is appears to be random as well.

I have absolutely no idea why, as I'm positive that I'm closing every resource once I no longer need it.

EDIT: I'd just like to stress that the exceptions are being thrown seemingly randomly. Sometimes it's thrown the first time a thread tries to execute a batch, other times the program will run without issues for a while (creating threads in the process, which all run absolutely fine) until the exception gets thrown. It's not linked to the amount of data that has been processed by the program so far (it's been anywhere from 0 to 60,000 entries).

Comment: You shouldn't need to close the connection explicitly in a try-with-resources block.

Comment: @Andy I realize that, but I did it just to be safe because the error was still getting thrown when I was only using try with resources.

Comment: "Locked" means that somebody else is accessing the same database. Are you sure that each thread is using only its own .db?

Comment: @CL. yes, the "num" variable that is referenced when creating a file path is a variable that is set when each thread is created, and I made sure that each thread has a different value set for that. So the first thread only outputs to database1.db, the second one to databes4.db, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check if executeBatch() and commit() are both synchronous functions... Also, you could try setting the database to serialized or multi-thread mode just in case.